# How do i use the value of Ngmodel in a seperate file to display the value?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I am new to Angular and TypeScript. I have defined input field phone number and collected its value in text box. Now i want that value to be displayed when sending email to the admin. I tried the below code but its not working.
its throwing error while continous intgeration
**Declaration of instance field not allowed after declaration of instance method. Instead, this should come at the beginning of the class/interface
Here is the code**

```
<div class="text-input">
        <label i18n="@@phoneNumberTitle" for="phoneNumber">i18n</label>
        <input
          id="phoneNumber"
          autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="@@placeholderphoneNumberTitle"
          i18n-placeholder="@@placeholderphoneNumberTitle"
          name="phoneNumber"
          #phoneNumber="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)] = "phone_number"
          required
        />
```

this is the typescript code

```
 /**
     * Call service to send notification via email to admin
      */
        phone_number:any;
       sendEmailToNotificateAdmin(user) {
         const data = {
         to: environment.adminEmail,
         cc: '123vron@gmail.com',
         subject: 'A new user has registered',
         body: `
             A new user has registered at XYB.

              Phone Number: ${this.phone_number}

          };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is by using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with `backtick` like this:

```
const age = 2;
const message = `I am ${age} years old`.
```

In your code, you are using parenthesis, change it to curly brackets.
Somewhere in your .ts component file you should have a variable called `phone_number` in order to capture the input.

```
 @Component({...})
 export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  phone_number: string;

  constructor() {}
   
  public ngOnInit(): void {}

  sendEmailToNotificateAdmin(user) {
     const data = {
     to: environment.adminEmail,
     cc: '123vron@gmail.com',
     subject: 'A new user has registered',
     body: `
         A new user has registered at XYB.

           Phone Number: ${this.phone_number}
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! here i cant define the value of phone number the way you have defined const age =2. I am accepting the value form user.

Comment: I want to use the value of phone number from ngmodel to display it in the email being sent to admin

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Sorry this didnt work for me. Instead i chose to add   phone_number:any;
and then changed the line to  Phone Number: ${this.phone_number}. i have edited my code in the question. please have a look. problem now is its running on my localhost but it gave me errors when i commited my code on Bitbucket